# Flutter Hot Restart - suspect it populates class instances incorrectly

Tags: class, flutter, instance, restart

My app is in 2 parts. It creates a widget tree and populates a Stateful Widget `Config`.

I then pass this to phase 2 of my app as a static. (I tried various ways).

On a clean emulator it runs fine.  When I run it again using *Hot Restart* my *buildSitePath* is passed  a half-baked instance that did not go thru the proper constructors.

Thus where `appCfg` is a static `Config appCfg`
that has been confirmed to be populated properly the log statement in the following will execute after
the populating and yet it will be the half-baked instance that breaks the app.  This happens on *Hot Restart* which supposedly restarts the app from the beginning.

```
  routes:<String,WidgetBuilder>{
          "/site":(BuildContext context) {assert(log("site: $appCfg"));
          return  buildSitePath(context,appCfg,title);}
        },
```

The solution was to not use a static and to use a onGenerateRoute and pass the actual instance as a parameter. Thus, this worked.

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  log("onGenerateRoute ${settings.name}");
  if (settings.name == "/site") {
    Config appCfg = settings.arguments;
    log("onGenerateRoute $appCfg");
    if (isMaterial(contextA)) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => buildSitePath(contextA, appCfg, title));
    } else {
      return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => buildSitePath(contextA, appCfg, title));
    }
  }
  return null;
```

I looked and found no understanding as to what *Hot Restart* is doing with classes that might explain this.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my question my suspicion is that *Flutter Hot Restart* sees the static class instance that is not populated and jams the class in there using a default constructor.

Even if the class was not static but a member of another class the same ailment persisted.

I record this behavior here so that others need not waste as much time as I did to understand the problem.